# Get accent color from a background agent in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone

In my background agent I try to get the current accent color:

```
SolidColorBrush brush = App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
```

But I get "App doesn't exist in the current context". And I can't resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IsolatedStorage` for sharing such data. In the application itself, write the current accent brush color to the isolated storage and access it in the backround agent.